# Fix the code used to solve Search for a Range

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

The following code targets on a leetcode problem -- [Search for a Range](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-for-a-range/description/) (**Please click to see the details**). The runtime complexity of the code has not been optimized, but it hasn't been expected to have some bug. Could you help me find where the bug is?
The code and its result are as follows.

**The code:**

```
/**
 * Return an array of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* searchRange(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*returnSize));
    a[0] = -1;
    a[1] = -1;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numsSize && a[0] == -1; i++){
        if(nums[i] == target)
            a[0] = i;
    }
    for(int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++){
        if(nums[j] == target)
            a[1] = j;
    }
    return a; 
}
```

**Run Code Result:**

Your input

```
[5,7,7,8,8,10]
8
```

Your answer

```
[]
```

Expected answer

```
[3,4]
```

Comment: @Mulliganaceous I expect it to have no bugs though its runtime complexity is not good. I will edit the question to make the expression clear.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous It seems that you haven't read the question the code was targeted to. The variables you mentioned had been specified, all I have to do is to fill the function.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous See the **Run Code Result** part of my question. The variables are offered by the [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-for-a-range/description/) to test whether my code is valid.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous You haven't understood my problem. Have you clicked that link to see what's going on?

Comment: `*returnSize` is a return value, you are using it before it gets a useful value.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can help you debug it.

Comment: do NOT post links to code, post the actual code as part of the question.  Otherwise, the question is 'off topic' and will receive 'close' votes.

Comment: @user3629249 The link is not for my code, but for the problem my code was targeted to. I used the link because that problem is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misbehaviour can be explained by your code using the value of the variable pointed to by `*returnSize`. Your output implies that the value is 0.
Juding from the name and from the general purpose, you need to find out the suitable value for that variable and write it via the pointer `returnSize` BEFORE using it.
You are using it among other things for mallocing the return memory, to a size of 0. This makes any access to any mmember member of `a` very questionable, e.g.

```
a[0] = -1;
a[1] = -1;
```

The fact that your output has zero numbers, is probably a loop (not shown) which simply does noting for `returnSize == 0`.

I recommend first to determine the number of occurences of the target value and the first index.
Then write that value via `*returnSize`.
Then malloc and array of appropriate size.
Then fill the array with a loop 0 to size-1, with `first_index + counter`.